# Best way to bind background color property of a custom control

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am creating a custom button control in WPF, and when I try to use it, the background brush property in the designer, it changes nothing. This is of course because I need to bind the properties together in XAML. I've tried:

```
<Button Content="Button" Background="{Binding Background, FallbackValue=White}"/>
```

If I don't use the fallbackvalue, I am able to use the designer to set the background color, but using it, I can't which means I cannot set a default. Any ideas?

Comment: If this is in a UserControl, you should write `{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a Custom Control (not UserControl), and there is a Control Style with a ControlTemplate, try this:

```
Background="{TemplateBinding CtlBackground}"
```

Assuming that "CtlBackground" is the name of your dependency property for background (of course, you can use the standard dependency property "Background").